# Python switch case statement returning 2 values per case but unsorted

Tags: python

I've implemented switch case statement in Python and want to return two values per case. I am getting unsorted results and while debugging I see that the impl_switch once created in unsorted that is, lengthy text and "ST" interchange order.

```
def FindPrototype(var):
    impl_switch = {
        "WG_JFN_DOL":       {"LOOONG TEXT 4", "ST"},
        "WG_JFN_RDOL":      {"LOOONG TEXT 13", "ST"},
        "WG_JFN_VSD":       {"LOOONG TEXT 2", "0"},
        "WG_JFN_VSD_UNI":   {"LOOONG TEXT 1", "ST"}
    }
    return impl_switch.get(var,"Empty")
```

When I run `Prototype, V230V = FindPrototype(var)` the result is not in sequence; the `prototype` and `V230V` values are interchanged. For some cases I get the `LOOONG TEXT` in `Prototype` and for others `V230V` has the `LOOONG TEXT`.

Any way I can force the case statement to return the values in fixed sequence?

Comment: Side-note: Put the definition of the `dict` outside the function, or it gets built from scratch every time (which means you saved *nothing* by using a `dict`, you may as well have just used `if`/`elif`/`else` tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `(tuples)` instead of `{sets}` to preserve the order of the values. Sets are unordered collections of unique values; duplicate values are removed, and order is not preserved. Tuples are like lists, but immutable; items are stored in order, can be accessed by numeric index, and duplicates are allowed.

```
"WG_JFN_DOL":       ("LOOONG TEXT 4", "ST"),
"WG_JFN_RDOL":      ("LOOONG TEXT 13", "ST"),
"WG_JFN_VSD":       ("LOOONG TEXT 2", "0"),
"WG_JFN_VSD_UNI":   ("LOOONG TEXT 1", "ST")
```